# GetList with a Library

Tags: development, list, infopath, libraries

I'm relatively new to SharePoint 2010 development and I recently rediscovered the [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.linq.datacontext_methods%28v=office.14%29.aspx) class.  Of particular interest right now is the GetList method.  I've seen examples and sample code around the Interwebs about how to use it, but most of the time it is used with Lists, List items, and the like.

Unfortunately, I'm working with a Library at the moment, not a List.  Can GetList also work with Libraries as well as Lists?  If not, is there a similar way to update individual items in a Library from an InfoPath 2010 form code behind in C#?

Thank you all in advance for help and advice!

Comment: Here is a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726974/access-sharepoint-document-library-from-web-application

Comment: It should yes, lists and libraries are the same thing when it comes to the API, they just have a different piece of internal metadata that denotes it's a library vs a list (for display porposes I believe).